# How to fill Repeater only on first Load

Tags: asp.net, repeater

In my page, I load various sections after the initial Page load, via Postbacks and `.Visible = true`. I have a Repeater control which I want to fill from a data source, but only the first time I load the Control.

Initially, I had tried something like the following, which is obviously not correct:

```
void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Repeater1.DataSource == null)
    {
        Repeater1.DataSource = GetDataInitial(); // Does the query of the data source
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

In short, I am trying to query some set of properties to tell me whether or not something has already bound data to it. I can't use `!Page.IsPostBack` since the Load may happen on a Post-Back.

If it helps, we can assume that I am only loading this section on the `Click` event of the control `Button1`.

Comment: ***PreRender*** event is too late to bind any control. Without seeing the rest of the code, I could not suggest any alternative.

Comment: You say "this is obviously not correct" but I don't exactly see what's obvious about it. You shouldn't do that in PreRender, but  is there some reason that checking to see if the data source is null wouldn't work?

Comment: @mason: `Repeater1.DataSource` will always have a `null` value unless the code assigns to it. So, on first load the `DataBind` code would run. But, it would also run on any other Postback, even if you've made changes to the repeater via its View State.